# Convert HTML Image URLs to Data URIs in Java

Tags: java, html, uri

I have some custom code that delivers .HTML files to the server's disk and I want to be able to revise that code to change all image references from normal URLs (ie `http://example.com/image.jpg`) to Base64 encoded Data URIs.

How can I parse this output (.html file) in Java and change all the img src's to Data URIs?

The HTML is basically an email so it could be like:

```
    <html>
       <body>
          <img src="http://www.google.co.uk/images/nav_logo242.png">
       </body>
    </html>
```

It needs to replace all `img src=` with the Base64 Data URIs.

My enter HTML email is Base64 encoded already as part of the delivery process we have, so I've only got as far as decoding and recoding it.  I have absolutely no idea how to swap out the Referenced Images with Data URIs.

> UPDATE

I have made some progress, and this now takes and inputs and spits out what I am after.  I am having issues with when the site is a HTTP one and then has to redirect to HTTPS.  That makes the code fall over.

```
package embedimages;

import com.github.kevinsawicki.http.HttpRequest;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class EmbedImages {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {

        boolean debug = false;

        String HTMLSTring = "<!DOCTYPE html>" + "<html>" + "<head>" + "<title>Example</title>" + "</head>" + "<body>" + "<table><tr><td><h1>HelloWorld</h1></tr>" + "</table>" + "<img src=\"http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/025B/production/_85730600_monkey2.jpg\">" + "</body>" + "</html>";

        if (debug) {
            System.out.println(HTMLSTring);
        }

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(HTMLSTring, "UTF-8");

        for (Element element : doc.select("img")) {
            String src = element.attr("src");
            if (debug) {
                System.out.println("Parsed src is: " + src);
            }

            if (src != null && !src.startsWith("data:")) {

                HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.get(src);
                request.trustAllCerts();
                request.trustAllHosts();
                if (debug) {
                    System.out.println("Header is: " + request.headers());
                }

                if (debug) {
                    System.out.println("Status is: " + request.code());
                }

                if (request.ok()) {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    request.receive(baos);
                    String mimeType = request.contentType();

                    if (debug) {
                        System.out.println(mimeType);
                    }
                    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

                    String encoded = HttpRequest.Base64.encodeBytes(b);
                    String dataURI = "data:" + mimeType + ";base64," + encoded;
                    if (debug) {
                        System.out.println(dataURI);
                    }

                    element.attr("src", dataURI);

                } else {

                    if (debug) {
                        System.out.println("FAIL");;
                    }
                }
                doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(true);

                if (debug) {
                    System.out.println(doc.html());
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: can you give us a basic example of such an html flie?

Comment: @Genzotto - added what I have done so far :)